# Pre-crash iphone symptoms - odd user position, volume change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm seeing intermittent strange symptoms in my app:

1. Blue blob (user position in MKMapView) starts "exploding" (odd, jerky animation).  Can begin at startup and seems to indicate eventual problems.
2. Speaker volume suddenly increases (back to level before I invoked kAudioSessionSetProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck).  The app keeps running, but this change tells me to expect no more sounds from AVAudioPlayer. Also a reliable indicator of a future crash (on save, etc).

I'm having trouble provoking this in the debugger (seems to only happen with movement in GPS).  Any ideas to track it down?

One possibility: could slow code (only executed when moving) cause the problem?

Comment: What version of iPhone OS does your build target? What device is this running on? What version of iPhone OS does your device use?

Comment: I'm targeting 3.0 and running this on an iPhone 3GS with 3.1.3 (7E18) installed.

Comment: this needs migrated to superuser as it is not a programing question

Comment: @Fred Grott: "I'm seeing intermittent strange symptoms in my app:" it's definitely a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This symptom (odd blinking blue user location) appears to be caused by memory corruption.

Tracked it to usage of

```
self.audioPlayer = nil
```

instead of

```
[audioPlayer release];
```